# How to ensure GC when subscribing to observable

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a class that takes in an `Observable` and subscribes to it.

```java
static class Helper {
    void subscribeTo(Observable<Object> observable) {
        observable.subscribe(someObject -> {
            // do something with someObject;
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any way that this class *itself* can be sure it unsubscribes when set to `null`?

```java
void main() {
    Helper helper = new Helper();
    Observable<Object> observable = ... // an observable that never completes
    helper.subscribeTo(observable);

    ...

    helper = null; // helper will never be GC'd because observable never completes
}
```

In this example `Helper` is very easy to abuse if you give it a never-ending `Observable`.

The best solution I can come up with is to allow (but not enforce) the instantiating class cleans up the helper class before setting to null:

```java
static class Helper {

    private Disposable disposable;

    void subscribeTo(Observable<Object> observable) {
        // do something with someObject;
        disposable = observable.subscribe(someObject -> {
            // do something with someObject;
        });
    }

    void cleanup() {
        disposable.dispose();
    }
}

void main() {
    Helper helper = new Helper();
    Observable<Object> observable = ... // an observable that never completes
    helper.subscribeTo(observable);

    ...

    helper.cleanup();
    helper = null;
}
```

Comment: Late update but: Since I'm using this in an Android context, I made `Helper` implement `Closable` and then used StrictMode to find out times when main() did not call close before nulling out via `detectLeakedClosableObjects`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder.html#detectLeakedClosableObjects()

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to rely on the user to unsubscribe somehow.  Why not just pass them back the `disposable` and let them use that?

```java
static class Helper {
    Disposable subscribeTo(Observable<Object> observable) {
        return observable.subscribe(someObject -> {
            // do something with someObject;
        });
    }
}
```